# Animate back when panel has been closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some arrows on the right side of my panels. So when I click on them, they get rotated.

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
});
```

I would now like to rotate them back to the starting point if the panel has been closed.

My code is not very advanced but this is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/xvrccycm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use JavaScript for that. You can change transform based on the `collapsed` class.

```
.panel-heading .arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.panel-heading .collapsed .arrow {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xvrccycm/4/)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thank you, that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('turn');
});
```

css:

```
.turn{
  -webkit-transform : rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with following code..

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {

    var _flag; 
    // storing previous state..
    if(!$(this).attr('rotated'))
        _flag = true;
    else
        _flag = false;

    $(".arrow").css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)').removeAttr('rotated'); // this will reset all other arrow..


   // Applying new state...
    if(_flag)
       $(this).attr('rotated',true).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an open state and check that

```
var open = false;
$('.arrow').click(function() {
  open = !open;
  if(open)
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
  else
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xvrccycm/5/)**