# Resetting Bootstrap Panel Heading after closing Panel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an accordion in bootstrap. I have it set to change the panel heading and glyphicon upon clicking open the panel I want. Also, when I click another panel, the previous panel resets to it's closed state.

However, the issue that I'm having is that if I click the same panel closed after opening it, the styling shows in it's "opened" state [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzHZ7.png)

What can I do to make sure that if I click a panel closed, it resets to its closed state? Below is the JQuery Code I'm working with.

```
$('.panel-clr').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    $(this).find('span').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
});

$('.panel-clr').click(function () {
    $('.panel-clr').not(this).removeClass('on');    
    $('.panel-clr').not(this).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $('.panel-clr').not(this).find('span').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
});
```

The CSS for the specific area is as follows:

```
.panel-clr.on {
background-color: #9D1E3A;
color: white; }
```

And Bootstrap for good measure:

```
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading alternate panel-clr" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                    Collapsible Group 1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:** I tried the CSS transform method, but nothing seemed to work right.

Comment: Have you tried toggleClass() ? Then you don't need to repeat the same function with not()

Comment: toggleClass changes them all at once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate back when panel has been closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908276/animate-back-when-panel-has-been-closed)

Comment: You don't have to use JS for this. Look at my answer in that thread above. Just use collapsed class to determine if your panel is open or not and add proper styles to your CSS.

Comment: @makshh I'm trying to use your method, but nothing seems to be taking whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery. You don't need two click event handlers for the buttons so you can remove the second event handler.

```
$('.panel-clr').click(function () {
    var panel = $(this);
    panel.toggleClass('on');
    var icon = panel.find('span').first();
    icon.toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    panel.siblings().removeClass('on');
    panel.siblings().find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
});
```

**jsFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwvtz1r3/

Comment: It kind of works, but now it leaves everything red. and flip flops the arrows if I click a different panel. I figured out something that does work, which is below, though it doesn't change the color how I want:


`function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-clr')
    .find('span')
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);`

Comment: @M.Straw try the link I added and tell me what the problem is. I'm not really following on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok it works! I had something in my CSS that was causing conflicts!

Comment: @M.Straw glad I could help!